# Lower Triangle Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a [lower triangle matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Description), without imports (though I use a math import in the beginning). The function I have written takes a list of DNA sequences, and compares them and inputs a float in a list of lists. The problem, however is that I accidentally created the upper triangle. Here is my code (I'll include the other functions so it might make sense):

```
def sequence_difference(seq1, seq2):
    counter = 0

    if len(seq1) == len(seq2):
        for i in range(len(seq1)):
            if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
                 counter += 1
        return counter / len(seq1)

    else:
         return ''

def jukes_cantor(diff):
    K = -(3/4) * log(1 - (4/3) * diff)
    return K

def lower_trian_matrix(list_of_seq):
    matrix = []

    for i in range(len(list_of_seq)):
         matrix.append([])

         for j in range(i + 1, len(list_of_seq)):
            matrix[i].append(jukes_cantor(sequence_difference(list_of_seq[j], list_of_seq[i])))     
    return matrix

sequences = ['TAAAAAAAAAAA',
             'TTAAAAAAAAAA', 
             'AAAAAAAAAAGG', 
             'AAAAAAAAGGGG']

print(lower_trian_matrix(sequences))
```

It outputs:

```
[[0.08833727674228764, 0.30409883108112323, 0.6081976621622466], 
 [0.4408399986765892, 0.8239592165010822], 
 [0.18848582121067953], 
 []]
```

But I want it to output:

```
[[], 
 [0.08833727674228764], 
 [0.30409883108112323, 0.4408399986765892], 
 [0.6081976621622466, 0.8239592165010822, 0.18848582121067953]]
```

The `sequence_difference` returns how different two sequences are in frequencies. The `jukes_cantor` returns a corrected estimate of how much the sequences actually have changed over the course of evolution.

Comment: *"without imports (though I use a math import in the beginning)"* - ? Do you mean no third-party libraries? If you have imports please include them in the code above so it's a [mre]. Also you didn't provide the input. How are we supposed to run this?

Comment: I do not use any libraries. This is a project for school, and we are not allowed to use libraries, except the math library. I use this in the beginning:

from math import log

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the necessary information

Comment: I hope it is easier to look at now. :)

Comment: Thank you very much @Tomerikoo for all the help. And sorry for all the trouble. :)

Comment: That's understandable. You're new, and I'm happy to help! Just try to learn from my edits of your question how a question should look like and make sure to go over (again) some basic stuff in the [help] like [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. You can also take the [tour]. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse the indexing for `i` and `j`:

```
from math import log

def sequence_difference(seq1, seq2):
    counter = 0

    if len(seq1) == len(seq2):
        for i in range(len(seq1)):
            if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
                counter += 1
        return counter / len(seq1)

    else:
        return ''

def jukes_cantor(diff):
    K = -(3/4) * log(1 - (4/3) * diff)
    return K

def lower_trian_matrix(list_of_seq):
    matrix = [[]]

    for i in range(1, len(list_of_seq)):
        matrix.append([])

        for j in range(i):
            matrix[i].append(jukes_cantor(sequence_difference(list_of_seq[j], list_of_seq[i])))     
    return matrix

sequences = ['TAAAAAAAAAAA',
             'TTAAAAAAAAAA', 
             'AAAAAAAAAAGG', 
             'AAAAAAAAGGGG']

print(lower_trian_matrix(sequences))
```

Alternatively, rename it to `def upper_trian_matrix(list_of_seq):` and tell your teacher, you always wanted to create the upper triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Print this line matrix.append([]) below this for loop `for j in range(i + 1, len(list_of_seq)): matrix[i].append(jukes_cantor(sequence_difference(list_of_seq[j], list_of_seq[i])))`

Currently, it is above, hence it is executing first.

Comment: Now it returns:
[[0.08833727674228764, 0.30409883108112323, 0.6081976621622466], [0.4408399986765892, 0.8239592165010822], [0.18848582121067953], [], [], []]